# AJAX call Without an API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

[image: error html][image: INDEX Screenshot]

In the moment I click on *new collection* list item all the cars that I have saved in my JSON comes on the webpage.

**HTML code**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">NEWST</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>  <a href="#">New collection</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gifts and sales</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service centers</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
      <!--<button onclick="addimage();"> Click</button>-->
    </div>
```

I wanted to make it dynamic but for it I need an API from which i could fetch the information by giving the URL of it. But right now I just saved the data in JSON and called it through AJAX.

**AJAX code :**

```
var clickedLi = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/scripts/car.json",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        BuildNewList(result,clickedLi);
    },
    error: function(err) {

    }
});

function BuildNewList(jsonData,liTag){ 
    liTag.empty(); 
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    liTag.append('New Collection<ul></ul>');

    {
        for (var make in data.cars) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.cars[make].length; i++) {
                var model = data.cars[make][i].model;
                liTag.find('ul').append('<li>' + make + ' - ' + model + '</li>')
            }
        }
}
```

**JSON :**

```
var anotherData = '{"cars":
    {"Honda":[
        {"model":"Figo"},
        {"model":"City"}
        ],
    "Audi":[
    {"model":"A6"},
    {"model":"A8"}
        ]
    }
}';
```

But it is not getting populate and not getting shown on the screen.

Why is it not giving me any output? And whether the *Success:* part in ajax is wrong or JSON object is having haul? I'm getting this errors:

[image: another errors][image: error]

Where am I wrong and how can i resolve it? AND one more thing is that I am confused whether my json file URL which I have given in AJAX is correct or not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot of console. and yes there are errors.

Comment: seems like jquery include problem

Comment: Shall I provide here he entire JQ code. As I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is not loading. It's getting `file` protocol which should not be the case here.

inlcude your jquery as:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
```

Also, make sure it's running on localserver since you're using AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And this is the main issue that what would come in the URL of JSON file that I am adding in AJAX? Is my AJAX code is right ? according to the desired result or some problem is there?

Comment: Yes because the jQuery is not loaded it making all things messed up which are dependent on it.
Your AJAX section seems to be alright nevertheless.

Comment: JQuery is added and hence first error has been resolved. I was adding an older one. :) thank you.. But why this Ajax/googleapi error is coming ? IS the URL provided by me in AJAX is correct ?

Comment: This ajax/googleapi error is not due to your AJAX code, it's because you're using CDN to load jQuery. What are the errors now?

Comment: Remove 1.9.1 version of jQuery, also what's in car.json:1 ?

Comment: Thanks. The JSON code above which i have provided. I have given it a name car.json so that can give the file name in AJAX URL.

Comment: Your cars.json file should be like this: `{"cars":
    {"Honda":[
        {"model":"Figo"},
        {"model":"City"}
        ],
    "Audi":[
    {"model":"A6"},
    {"model":"A8"}
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: You are telling me the javascript object not the JSON.. JSON is right but what with the errors. why am i getting those errors in console ? And i am extremely sorry for replying so late as I lost my internet connection.

Comment: what's inside cars.json file?

Comment: Your JSON file should not be like a JS file. DONOT use variables. Just paste this only in json file: `{"cars":
    {"Honda":[
        {"model":"Figo"},
        {"model":"City"}
        ],
    "Audi":[
    {"model":"A6"},
    {"model":"A8"}
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: Tell me one thing that what makes the above code different from Javascript object ?? What is the difference ?? Don't you think that its a javascript object ?? you mean to say that i do not need to save it in a variable ??

Comment: still the same error persisting. I have added a screenshot of html where there is an error.

Comment: You need to remove this line or put it in comments `Load JSON file locally...`

Comment: When the JSON is in file.JSON file name it shouldn't be in a variable. When it's in JSON is in file.JS then it should be in a variable.

Comment: Oh all right...So i better avoid using variable... And that comment either way is not affecting the code of HTML.. The error still persists.

Comment: Do i really need to use *LOAD()* function ??

Comment: The same.. One is in car.JSON and another in HTML LINE 13.